# Python : ValueError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 1 while using requests.json()

Tags: python, node.js, nginx

I am using a nodejs express server that sends data to a python client. The nodejs express server sends data using res.send() function and the returned data is huge and sometimes when I am processing the data at the python side using response.json() function I get this error. Here are is my understanding of the error , either the python side the entire request was not read or the node server truncated the data when it reached a maximum size.
Here are my questions:
1. Am I supposed to use res.json() instead of res.send() ? Since to my understanding res.json() also calls res.send() inturn. 
2. Am I supposed to stream the response data in python ? is that a good option? or is it even an option ? 
3. Is this a configuration issue ? As I understand there are ways to configure the nginx server that is connecting these microservices to limit the amount of data transferred? 
4. Is there way to ensure that data transmitted from the node server always contains the complete json. Liking parseing the body before sending it.

I am beginner and If I had made any mistakes or suggestions in the questions, do point them out.

Comment: For error message seems there is a malformed/incomplete JSON data. I guess you are using Python requests module of client side to process response: you can try to inspect content of response with: response.content to evaluate if response content is a valid JSON.

Comment: The problem is it only occurs in an environment where I do not a authorisation, hence I am trying to figure it out on my own.